# Can't change UINavigationBar Custom Font Color

Tags: swift, fonts

I am using Storyboard and I want to change the UINavigationBar title color to `UIColor.whiteColor()` on one of my ViewControllers. Xcode is recognizing the font, but I can't change the color.

I Tried:
 changing it with both Storyboard and  with code below, but it does not seem to work. I also tried using different fonts and both .otf and .ttf thinking it might be caused by an error with the fonts. So far I can only get a black color with any custom font.

```
 var nav = self.navigationController!.navigationBar
    self.navigationItem.title = "HOME"
    nav.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    nav.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Impact", size: 30)!]
```

[image]

Comment: If I leave off your last line, the color changes correctly.  Can't seem to get the last line to run on my system.

Comment: Yes, it works -- but I want to use the Custom font not the system font. Leaving out the last line will change the color of the System font inside the  UINavigationBar , which is not what I am looking for. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This way it does indeed change the title color, but unfortunately it also changes the custom font to a regular system font.

Comment: Are you wanting to change just the font color of the navigation bar in one view? or across the app? If you want the change all over, I would use UIAppearance in the app delegate.

Comment: @ SefTarbell Yes just one view,  Thanks for letting me know the other option, I will need it some day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you need to set the attributes at the same time like this:

```
nav.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Impact", size: 30)!]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the navigation bar's tintColor property to your desired color.